# Redundant matplotlib.text.Text objects

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

This Python 3.8.10 and matplotlib 3.5.1 code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as text

plt.axis('off')
print(plt.findobj(match=text.Text))
plt.show()
```

produces an empty viewer window:

[image]

and this list with many duplicates:

```
[Text(0.5, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0.5, ''), Text(0, 0.5, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0.5, 1.0, ''), Text(0.0, 1.0, ''), Text(1.0, 1.0, '')]
```

What are they? Are they necessary? How to prevent them from being created? How to get rid of them?

---

My objective is to interactively add and remove text labels. Presence of these initial text objects, which can't be removed, makes it more complex. Ideally, I would like to have a function to remove all text labels. I create a set of context dependent labels based on mouse click coordinates and remove and regenerate the whole set on the next click.

Comment: What are the characteristics of the text elements that you want to distinguish from these automatically generated axis ticklabels? Do they all appear in the image? Maybe one can filter differently for visible or bbox artists.

Comment: @Mr.T I added a bit more context to my post. Technically, it's not a big problem. I can store references to new text labels and use them for removal at each cycle. I wanted to make sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel by missing some obvious functionality in Matplotlib.

Comment: As the `remove() method` is not established for axis-inherent objects like tick labels and titles, you can collect all current text objects instantiated by you with `my_text = [item for item in ax.findobj(match=text.Text)] if item._remove_method]`.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you. This is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You created these text objects because with `plt.axis("off")`, you initiated an axis object with standard x-/y-ticks and corresponding tick labels, i.e., the text objects. I assume, for matplotlib, to set an axis invisible, it must exist, but I haven't looked into the source code to verify this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as text

text_before = plt.findobj(match=text.Text)
plt.axis('off')
text_after = plt.findobj(match=text.Text)

print("before ", text_before)
print("after ", text_after)

#plt.show()
```

Output:

```
before  []    
after  [Text(0.5, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(0, 1, ''), Text(0, 0.5, ''), Text(0, 0.5, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0, 0, ''), Text(1, 0, ''), Text(0.5, 1.0, ''), Text(0.0, 1.0, ''), Text(1.0, 1.0, '')]
```

Even just trying to locate the current axis initiates the generation of a figure and axis that didn't exist before:

```
print("before", plt.get_fignums())
plt.gca()
print("after", plt.get_fignums())
```

Output:

```
before []
after [1]
```

I think there is no need to remove the text objects as they will not influence the rendering of the final image and are rather inert for image generation. And it seems the removal of axis-inherent text artists like tick labels and titles (as well as Line2D objects representing spines and ticks) is also not implemented by matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as text

#the axis object itself can be removed
ax = plt.gca()
#the axis-inherent objects title and tick labels (and not tested here spine and tick Line2D objects)
#cannot be removed
ax_title = plt.title("This is the title") 
_, (ax_label, _, _) = plt.xticks(range(3), list("ABC"))
#text added by user can be removed
ax_text_visible = ax.annotate("This text is visible", (0.30, 0.20), xycoords="axes fraction")
ax_text_invisible = ax.annotate("This text is not visible", (0.20, 0.50), xycoords="axes fraction", visible=False)
ax_text_outside = ax.annotate("This text is outside the canvas", (20, 50), xycoords="axes fraction")
ax_text_not_annotation = plt.text(0.3, 0.7, "Not an annotation")
#test generated objects for existence of the remove method 
test_list = [ax, ax_title, ax_label, ax_text_visible, ax_text_invisible, ax_text_outside, ax_text_not_annotation]
#generate a list of user-created Text objects that ignores axis-inherent text objects
removable_objects = [item for item in test_list if item._remove_method]
for item in removable_objects:
    print(item, type(item))
```

Output:

```
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77) <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
Annotation(0.3, 0.2, 'This text is visible') <class 'matplotlib.text.Annotation'>
Annotation(0.2, 0.5, 'This text is not visible') <class 'matplotlib.text.Annotation'>
Annotation(20, 50, 'This text is outside the canvas') <class 'matplotlib.text.Annotation'>
Text(0.3, 0.7, 'Not an annotation') <class 'matplotlib.text.Text'>
```

So, we can use the `remove()` method to identify all text that the user has placed on the axis (excluding titles and tick labels):

```
#test that all removable user text is also found when screening with ax.findobj(match=text.Text)
matched_text = [item for item in ax.findobj(match=text.Text) if item._remove_method] 
print(set(matched_text) == set(removable_objects[1:])) 
>>>True
```

Comment: I added a motivation to my question.

Comment: I have seen your previous question, so I think I know why you asked this one. Maybe the matplotlib team at GitHub can tell you a way to remove Text Artists. You can post then the answer here.